# check if an element has length zero in an array and do something with that element on javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-5, zero, string-length

I want to know if some elements in an array has length zero, and with those elements I want to change the color for example. all of this with javascript es5.

for example, I have a form with some inputs in there, I want to check if there is any input in that form with value length equal zero, and for those inputs that has value length equal zero I want to change the border color to red.

Comment: [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) please provide relevant data so your question will be more likely to get help faster

Comment: This sounds more like [a form validation issue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation), and you can probably do this simply [with CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid).

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet may help you in achieving the results.

```js
const checkVal = function(){
  let inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for(input of inputs){
    if(input.value.length == 0)
      input.style.borderColor="red";
      else
      input.style.borderColor="black";
  }
 }
```

```html
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<a href="javascript:" onclick="checkVal()">Check Empty Inputs</a>
```

Comment: thanks!! one more question, I need to add a p under every input with red border, I try using input.parentElement.appendChild(); but this only put the p on the last input

Comment: input.parentELement.innerHTML += "<p>Required</p>"
This can help.